# Numerical algorithms for geodesically convex optimization

Tags: riemannian-geometry, na.numerical-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I want to solve a minimization problem of the form

$\inf_{x \in M} f(x)$

where $M$ is a Hadamard manifold and $f$ is geodesically convex (but not differentiable). Since I know that in general a minimizer does not exist for my problem, I want to find near-minimizers. In the results that I found in the literature (like subgradient algorithms), it is often assumed that the set of minimizers is nonempty. And otherwise, the results don't even guarantee that the produced sequence of points eventually becomes nearly minimal. Are there results that I have overlooked?